# More classes and extern variable in C++

Tags: c++, class, global, extern

I've some troubles with linking files together. There are classes which I'm using:

**header of class A in file A.h**

```
class A
{
public:
    B someVariable;    //there is class B used!!
    int number;
};
```

**header of class B in file B.h**

```
class B
{
public:
    void someMethod();  
};
```

**implementation of B**

```
B::someMethod()
{
    cout << "Value is:" << globalInstanceOfA.number << "\n";
}
```

And then in another file I need to declare a global variable globalInstanceOfA, which i will use throughout the whole program...

But I can't solve out where to put include, extern and so on. I've tried something like that:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"

extern A globalInstanceOfA;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: You should place "B.h" before "A.h".

Comment: You got a design bug here, and and B should never know each other...

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
extern A globalInstanceOfA;
```

goes in a header file that you must include in order to use the variable `globalInstanceOfA`; this provides a *declaration* of the global variable.

The line

```
A globalInstanceOfA;
```

goes into any of your cpp files to provide a *definition* for the global variable. There must be exactly one definition among all cpp files in your program.

Comment: Hmmm. The `extern` doesn't need to go in a header. There's nothing wrong about it in a cpp. There's something moderately wrong with using it at all, however.

Comment: @Dave There is nothing wrong with `extern` being in a cpp file, but that's usually useless: one needs `extern` to share a global among multiple CPPs, that's why it's usually in a header. I do agree that there's something "moderately wrong with using globals" in general, though.

Comment: Pedantic: One doesn't need `extern` to share a global among multiple cpps, they need it to share a global among one or more cpps... which is why it's perfectly dirty/useful to use in a particular cpp, sometimes.